# How do I get HTML of Google Chrome URL?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, process, get

I am creating a project in Basic with Visual Studio that has to start Google Chrome, navigate to a site like "google.com" and then getting the source(HTML) of this site to a variable. How can I do that? 
Actually, I start with

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http:\\google.com")
```

But I am stuck with getting the HTML of the site.
Any help?
(Please don't tell me to create a webbrowser control, I need to get HTML back from Google Chrome and not via webbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a webbrowser control or starting process. Just try this:

```
Imports System.Net
```

---

```
Dim web As New WebClient()
Dim source As String = web.DownloadString("www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you out. It's in C# but VB can achieve exactly the same thing, only other syntax.

```
 string urlAddress = "http://google.com";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
 using(Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
 {
   using(StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream))
   {
    string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
   }
  }     
}
```

Side note: I don't know your requirement and I don't want to know but be aware that this concept is known as screen scraping, which is in the grey zone in terms of IT law.